# Strange compiler error during ShareKit integration

Tags: xcode, sharekit

I tried integrate ShareKit in my project and I face a problem.

By the time I include the ShareKit classes in my classes project folder the compiler gets errors like

"Parse Issue. Unknown type name 'NSUInteger'" or
"Parse Issue. Unknown type name 'NSString'"

in the MyProject_Prefix.pch file.

The variables I defined in the prefix file are globally used by my application. I have never got this kind of error before untill I included the ShareKit classes in my project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve this issue by moving all `#import` declarations and any other Objective-c code inside the `#ifdef __OBJC__` section.

So for example, if your pch file looks like this, it will cause compilation errors:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
typedef void (^BasicBlock)();
```

It must look like this, and those errors should go away:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
    typedef void (^BasicBlock)();
#endif
```

Comment: I hope you sir wear a cloak !